# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest firing more than once?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying an experiment to add a variable to a url using chrome's webRequest. The javascript is very simple.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var url = details.url + '?tag=test';
    return {redirectUrl: url};
  },
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking"]);
```

However, when I apply it to any domain I'm getting at least a double result of the variable. When I tested with cnn.com using direct nav I actually got the variable appended 4 times.

Here's the relevant snipped of the manifest.

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest", "*://*.letags.com/*", "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
```

Are there round trips happening between the browser and the server so the server is feeding the url back into the extension before actually displaying? If so, how would I structure a match query to recognize when the variable already exists?

Comment: I tried several different domains to see the problem was common to all sites. It appears to be. I originally skipped the url variable declaration and just added the string to details.url before returning it.

Comment: It's always good to state, what you have done. Nobody likes to do the Job of others, we just like to help. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var url = details.url + (/\?tag=/.test(details.url) ? "" : "?tag=test");
// Explained if details.url contains the text "?tag=" -> don't add Parameter
// Else if it doesn't contain the Parameter -> add it.
```

is not beautiful, but works.

[Here is a link to a Javascript reference for RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: Even better, don't redirect at all if the URL contains `?tag=test`. See `chrome://net-internals/` to see what actually happens - you're redirecting multiple times (although not visible).

Comment: Hi Rob. Where I'm headed eventually is validating that tag=test. If it doesn't, then I need to update it and redirect. If it already does, then I can just let the request roll.

Comment: @winner_joiner - That is working just fine. Thanks for the help!